# Is it possible to several commands in the background but wait for all results and fail the script if an command fails

Tags: bash, shell, curl, continuous-integration, sh

I have a CI script that I want to speed up by running several things in the background. I want the script wait for all processes and check each one to see if it failed.

Here a a simplification:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

bg()
{
    sleep .$[ ( $RANDOM % 10 ) + 1 ]s
}

bg2()
{
    sleep .$[ ( $RANDOM % 10 ) + 1 ]s
    exit 1
}

bg &   # will pass after a random delay 
bg2 &  # will fail after a random delay


# I want the output of the program to be a failure since bg2 fails
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

You can use the [`wait`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/wait) command in `bash` to wait for completion on one or more sub-processes to terminate in which case we provide the `PID` to wait on it. Also `wait` can optionally take no arguments in which case it waits for all background process to terminate.

Example:-

```
#!/bin/bash

sleep 3 &

wait "$!"     # Feeding the non-zero process-id as argument to wait command.
              # Can also be stored in a variable as pid=$(echo $!)

# Waits until the process 'sleep 3' is completed. Here the wait 
# on a single process is done by capturing its process id

echo "I am waking up"

sleep 4 &
sleep 5 &

wait          # Without specifying the id, just 'wait' waits until all jobs 
              # started on the background is complete.

# (or) simply
# wait < <(jobs -p)     # To wait on all background jobs started with (job &)

echo "I woke up again"
```

Update:-

To identify the jobs when the fail, it is best to loop over the list of background jobs and log their exit-code for visibility. Thanks to wonderful suggestion by [chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner). It goes like

```
#!/bin/bash
for p in $(jobs -p)
do
     wait "$p" || { echo "job $p failed" >&2; exit; }
done
```

Comment: @Robert: to get the process-id of the background job, a non-zero integer which is passed as argument to wait command.

Comment: This is missing a crucial aspect from the original question: failing if any background job fails. Waiting for multiple background processes loses information about their exit status; you need to wait on jobs individually to see if each succeeds or fails.

Comment: Also, `wait` does not read from standard input; I think you meant `wait $(jobs -p)` at the end.

Comment: @chepner: thanks for the catch! am afraid I know only how to keep track of the exit status when i run wait per process id, but with an overall `wait` without any process id, am at loss to keep track of the individual status'

Comment: @chepner - Yes you are right, after experimenting, I find the exit status is lost.  Ill rewrite the question to be clear.

Comment: Hm, seems I never submitted the follow-up comment I meant to. Anyway, you can loop over the jobs and wait for them individually: `for p in $(jobs -p); do wait "$p" || { exit; echo "job $p failed" >&2; }; done`. Starting in `bash` 4.3, you can use `while [[ "$(jobs -p)" ]]; do wait -n || { exit; ... }; done` to wait for jobs in the order they complete, although you lost information about *which* job just exited.

Comment: Good, you didn't use the `wait -n` version; it has the problem that if more than one job completes during an iteration, you won't actually `wait` on all of them.

Comment: I think the exit and the echo is in the wrong order... Ill edit

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

bg()
{
    sleep .$[ ( $RANDOM % 10 ) + 1 ]s
}

bg2()
{
    sleep .$[ ( $RANDOM % 10 ) + 1 ]s
    exit 1
}

export -f bg
export -f bg2

parallel ::: bg bg2 || echo $? of the jobs failed
```

Comment: Cool, presume I have to install https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/ ?

Comment: You presume correctly. But note that you do not need root access to do that.