# Make Shell script to wait until applescript finishes?

Tags: shell, unix, applescript

I have a shell script which calls an AppleScript. AppleScript runs some automated tests on a software with a given document.

After the AppleScript finishes its execution I am moving the document to some other folder using `mv` command in my shell script and then I am moving the next document so that AppleScript can run those tests with this new document. But as soon as AppleScript is called it moves the document to another folder without those tests being run on that document.

How can I give a wait in my shell script so that the document is moved only after the AppleScript has finished executing all the tests?

```
1. mv $file "/path/to/file" (Moving the document to the execution folder)
2.  osascript /pathto/applescript.app (it will use this execution folder to run its tests)
3.  mv "/path/to/file" /Users/Desktop/tempfolder (moving the document on which the test is completed to a temp folder)
```

Steps 2 and 3 go one after another without wait, hence the document on which the test is to be run is moved before the test completes.

Comment: Why this -1 . Please tell so that I can modify anything if required

Comment: Probably the down-voter wanted the see some "code", by which I mean whatever you verbally explained and also some "code" on your attempts to fix the problem.

Comment: Wait resolves the problem but its not a good solution as the test might take more time for specific files. I tried & but it wont work as even if the applescipt is made to run in background it will not have the file it wants for the tests to be run.

Comment: this recent question with an answer (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40215226/is-it-possible-to-several-commands-in-the-background-but-wait-for-all-results-an) looks to be good fit for your case too

Comment: This is what I mentioned in the comment. I cant run it in background because as soon as the next step i.e. step 3 is performed the file gets moved and step 2 has no file to process.

Comment: did you also add `wait "$!"` between step 2 and 3?

Comment: No it didn't help either. same is happening using the wait "$!".Any leads ??

Comment: You could exec 2 in a subshell, get the pid, do a while loop waiting for that pid to end its task? Can someone confirm this pls?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, shell commands are executed in-sequence. That is, the next statement is not run until the current one is done executing, whether or not it was successful. So if this is the case you can merely write your script one command after another.

I guess that `osascript /pathto/applescript.app` run some tasks in a different process, and that osascript returns from its own execution while the process doing "what you want" is still running.

What you could do would be to `ps -aux | grep applescript.app` then get the pid from that, and do a while loop afterward to see when the program cease. But that seem overengineered and you don't know the execution name of the applescript.app.

If I am wrong somewhere please anybody correct me

Answer (score 0):

As Mayerz said, do shell script command is waiting for end of instruction to move to next AppleScript command. In any case, you can also use the "considering application response" bloc. Here is an example with a move in Finder :

```
set A to ("myVolume:Users:Me:Documents:sample.mov") as alias
set B to ("Users:me:Desktop:") as alias
tell application "Finder"
    considering application responses
        move A to B
    end considering
end tell
display dialog "done"
```

Similar example with do shell script:

```
set A to ("myVolume:Users:Me:Documents:sample.mov") as alias
set B to path to desktop
set AU to POSIX path of A
set BU to (POSIX path of B) & "test2.mov"
tell application "Finder"
    considering application responses
        do shell script "mv " & (quoted form of AU) & " " & (quoted form of BU)
    end considering
end tell
display dialog "done"
```

Comment: I thought of doing the same before but I was not able to find the correct syntax for that. If suppose I want to move only those files which have the extension .mov what additions I have to make in your suggested solution.I tried with *.mov but it didnt work.

Comment: to get all the *.mov, the solution will depend if you use the Finder method or the steel script method. I is quite easy with Finder method because you can built list of file with something like "get every file of folder xxx whose name extension is "mov".

Comment: "considering application response" didn't solve the problem either. It is still jumping to the move command as soon as the test is triggered by the applescript.

Comment: which test ? there is no test. your 'mv' command should be inside the considering.../end considering block.